Can Spring MVC be used just for designing client side(front-end)?
I have some spring boot microservices and I want to use these microservices from a client application(front-end). If I use Spring MVC for designing the client side application, and from there, the client side application sends requests to the microservices REST APIs to use their services, is this a standard and correct solution?
I mean, designing the client side app using Spring MVC instead of frameworks like angular or react. But the main logic of the application resides in the spring boot microservices.
This image better shows the issue:

Sure, you can do this.  It's not uncommon for folks to use Spring MVC to write their front-end.  There are reasons why you wouldn't want to do this, but from an architecture perspective, this is perfectly acceptable.


tl;dr: Spring MVC will not contradict what you are trying to do, but as a technology this is not the main scenario it was built for.

First a short terminology clarification (a bit pedantic, but precision helps for the understanding):

I think when you say "Microservice", you mean "one RESTful service, as part of your backend". The term "Microservices" is usually only used in plural, referring to the structural patter of having multiple REST services at interplay in a backend.

Can / should you use Spring MVC for the scenario in mind?

The strong point of Spring MVC is a convenient exchange of variables between the static, server side created HTML pages (V) and the backend (C+M). E.g. a HTML form, where Spring MVC gives you convenient access to form fields, directly from your java code. The communication you describe (your frontend interacting with a REST API) is not part of this main Spring MVC purpose. However, Spring MVC is not per se ruling out the scenario you have in mind. HTML pages generated by Spring MVC may still contain code that fires requests to a REST API backend.

How is this usually done:

The communication of a web frontend with a REST backend usually works like this: Some JavaScript code, which is running on the client / frontend side issues fetch calls to send HTTP requests to the RESTful service / backend. The Javascript code (or rather the page containing the JavaScript code) can be delivered from anywhere. It can be part of your Spring MVC application, but you do not need Spring MVC to deliver webpages.


Concerning your last question: You can of course use React etc on client side, to issue requests to the API. But basic JavaScript will perfectly get the job done. In fact, adding a huge client side framework might likely add unnecessary complexity. I'd go with simple basic technologies, unless you have a strong reason / need to add a client sided framework. Similarly, the logic residing on the backend is not tied to Spring MVC as a backend technology. Any basic REST API can encapsulate backend logic.


You clarified it nicely and I got it very well. Thank you

So, HTML or React? The answer depends on your project’s requirements. If you’re starting with web development and need a simple, static website, HTML is your friend. It’s easy to grasp and does the job effectively.
However, if you’re aiming for highly interactive, dynamic web applications, React is the way to go. Its speed, efficiency, and rich functionality make it the preferred choice for modern web development.
In the end, the choice between HTML and React boils down to your specific project goals and your level of expertise. Both technologies have their strengths, and mastering both can be a valuable skill for any web developer.
In this HTML vs. React showdown, we’ve explored the working, functionality, performance, structure, and factors that drive developers’ choices. Now, armed with this knowledge, you can make an informed decision for your next web development venture.
Remember, the web development landscape is continually evolving, so stay curious and keep learning. Keep coding!
